# ASP.NET UnitTest используя Moq с Generic Repository и UnitOfWork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, asp.net-web-api

Пытаюсь сделать прирожения  **ASP.NET MVC WEBAPI** по [примеру](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte) c Generic Repository и UnitOfWork. 
Само приложение работает нормально, но возникла необходимость написать юнит тесты.
 Для тестирования использую библиотеку [Moq](https://github.com/Moq). Нужно протестировать 4 CRUD метода. 

 Я создаю mock-объект в отдельном методе как-то так:

```
        private IRepository<Country> CreateMockRepository()
        {
            Mock<IRepository<Country>> mock = new Mock<IRepository<Country>>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.Table).Returns(new Country[]
            {
                new Country {ID =1, Name ="Country1" },
                new Country {ID =2, Name ="Country2" }
            }.AsQueryable());

            return mock.Object;
        }
```

`IRepository` - интерфейс generic хранилища который объявляет в основном CRUD
`Country` - моя таблица с 2 полями

Дальше делаю метод для тестирования Post-метода

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Insert_Country()
    {
        //Arrange - create mock repository               
        var moq = CreateMockRepository();

        //Arrange - create a controller

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/country");
        var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}");
        var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "country" } });
        CountryController target = new CountryController(moq);
        target.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
        target.Request = request;
        target.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;

        Country newCountry = new Country(){ ID = 10, Name = "TEST" };

        //Action
        var result = target.Post(newCountry);
        var result2 = target.Get().ToArray();

        //Assert 1
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, result.StatusCode);            

        //Assert 2
        Assert.AreEqual(3, result2.Length);
    }
```

В результатке Assert1 проходит но Assert2 возвращает всеравно 2 записи. 

 Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? Если нужно будет код моей реализации контроллера, UnitOfWork.cs и класа который реализует репозиторий, я скину позже

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
        {
            Country toDelete = repository.GetById(id);

            if (toDelete == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            try
            {
                repository.Delete(toDelete);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody]Country country)
        {
            Country oldCountry = repository.GetById(country.ID);

            if (oldCountry == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            try
            {
                oldCountry.Name = country.Name;
                oldCountry.LastUpdDT = DateTime.Now;
                repository.Update(oldCountry);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, oldCountry);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведённом коде в моке задано только возвращение коллекции стран. Но не задана их вставка/сохранение.

В настройках мока должно быть что-то вроде:

```
private IRepository<Country> CreateMockRepository()
{
    var countries = new List<Country> {
        new Country { ID=1, Name="Country1" },
        new Country { ID=2, Name="Country2" }
    };

    Mock<IRepository<Country>> mock = new Mock<IRepository<Country>>();

    mock.Setup(m => m.Table).Returns(countries.AsQueryable());

    mock.Setup(m => m.Insert(It.IsAny<Country>()))
        .Callback<Country>(c => countries.Add(c));

    return mock.Object;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, это то, что было мне нужно. Спасибо