# Moq объект для тестирования

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, moq

```
public class WebSDb4 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserData> UserDatas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

как для такого контекста правильно написать moq?
P.S. не знаю, необходимо ли кидать описания всех моделей, получится довольно объемно.

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431827/184217 Вот только моки ДБ тестируют вставку/чтение в/из коллекции. И смысла в них почти ноль.